# Android. Как задать правильный цвет у элементов в API ниже 21

Tags: android, color, progress-bar, android-preferences, android-switch

Задал `accentColor` желтым и на `API > 21` все работает,
однако на API ниже появились проблемы - некоторые элементы управления синие

1. ProgressBar

Корректный вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Некорректный вид на `API < 21`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удалось пофиксить с помощью следующих строк:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.accent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

Как исправить данную проблему с помощью переопределения стиля `ProgressBar`?

2. Та же самая проблема с `Activity` настроек, с переключателями и названиями `PreferenceCategory` - как тут пофиксить вообще не представляю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если как то поможет выдержка из `xml`, где формирую элементы

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_category_start">

...

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_welcome_default_switch"
        android:key="@string/pref_welcome_key_switch"
        android:summary="@string/pref_welcome_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_welcome_string" />

...    

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Разметка прогрессБара

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: это в каком городе такая погода?)

Comment: Вопрос просто задан был еще в феврале :)

Comment: О блин, а то я испугался :D

Comment: то ли styles, то ли colors надо создать папку в проекте. Создаёшь styles-v21 или colors-v21, в проекте при этом файл будет раскрываться на 2 файла. Так вот, в файлах с окончанием -v21 пишешь строки для апи 21 и выше, в другом файле пишешь для апи ниже 21, причём в v21 будут доступны строки, которых нет в простом файле

Comment: style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal указывали у progressbar в xml? или перепоределить в стилях, в нем выставить нужные цвета, и пихнуть новый стиль в ProgressBar ? ну или вообще в AppTheme -  progressBarStyle - кинуть ссылку на новый стиль

Comment: Что пугаться: Оймякон  -8

Comment: Добавил описание ProgressBar из разметки

Comment: http://www.materialdoc.com/linear-progress/ там вроде в конце написано что нельзя поменять :(

Comment: там написано
ProgressBar is not displayed in material style on pre Lollipop devices.
Но то, что нельзя изменить цвет нет :) 
Я не думаю что до 21 АПИ все прогрессБары были синими

Comment: Нельзя конкретно через стили, программно ни кто не отменял ) я бы в таком случае сделал бы кастомный унаследованный ProgressBar. в нем при инициализации менял бы цвет. и потом указывал бы его в xml, в таком случае просто не нужно будет каждый раз в куске кода менять ему цвет

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй установить *colorControlNormal*, исходя из описание это непосредственно то что задаёт цвет компонентам. Для переключателя соответственно *colorSwitchThumbNormal*.

Из \sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml

```
<!-- The primary branding color for the app. By default, this is the color applied to the action bar background. -->
<attr name="colorPrimary" format="color" />

<!-- Dark variant of the primary branding color. By default, this is the color applied to the status bar (via statusBarColor) and navigation bar (via navigationBarColor). -->
<attr name="colorPrimaryDark" format="color" />

<!-- Bright complement to the primary branding color. By default, this is the color applied to framework controls (via colorControlActivated). -->
<attr name="colorAccent" format="color" />

<!-- The color applied to framework controls in their normal state. -->
<attr name="colorControlNormal" format="color" />

<!-- The color applied to framework controls in their activated (ex.checked) state. -->
<attr name="colorControlActivated" format="color" />

<!-- The color applied to framework control highlights (ex. ripples, list selectors). -->
<attr name="colorControlHighlight" format="color" />

<!-- The color applied to framework buttons in their normal state. -->
<attr name="colorButtonNormal" format="color" />

<!-- The color applied to framework switch thumbs in their normal state. -->
<attr name="colorSwitchThumbNormal" format="color" />
```

Comment: Добавил в корневой стиль приложения эти атрибуты

Без изменений: элементы PreferenceActivity синие на АПИ < 21


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете *PreferenceActivity*

1. Замените PreferenceActivity на соотв. наследника AppCompatActivity из appcompat-v7 библиотеки.
2. Используйте [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html).

Comment: Я их и использую

Comment: В таком случае, пожалуйста, укажите это в вопросе.